# How to use variables in windows commands to execute from ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, variables, ping

I have to execute a ping command from ruby script.
If I directly execute `ping 8.8.8.8` it works.

How can i use a variable in place of IP?

I tried

```
dst_ip="8.8.8.8"
ping_string = "ping "+dst_ip
puts ping_string
ping = `ping_string`
```

but it dint work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as below :

```
C:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> ip = '66.249.64.0'
=> "66.249.64.0"
irb(main):002:0> `ping #{ip}`
=> "\nPinging 66.249.64.0 with 32 bytes of data:\nRequest timed out.\nRequest ti
med out.\nRequest timed out.\nRequest timed out.\n\nPing statistics for 66.249.6
4.0:\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),\n"
irb(main):003:0>
```

You don't need to do string operation like this - `ping_string = "ping "+dst_ip`.

Answer (score 0):

Because interpolation works in `` operator, this should work:

```
ping = `#{ping_string}`
```